How do I write ‘Best friends since 1997’ in latin
This is for an engraving so I want to get it grammatically correct and I am very rusty! Both parties female. For my bestie of nearly 30 years. Also read that some words for female friend can have courtesan /sexual connotations and don’t want that lol.
‘Best friends since 1997’
TIA

Amicissimae ab 1997o

There are a few ways you could say this, but my suggestion is to use in amicitia ("in friendship") instead of "friends", and perhaps firmissima for "best", such as in Cicero's Pro Murena:

haec eadem res plurimas gratias, firmissimas amicitias, maxima studia pariat.
the same quality is apt to attract the most widespread gratitude, the sincerest friendships, and the warmest supporters.

It's a touching sentiment. Others attest to amicitia firma as being a normal of way of saying "good friends."
With amicitia, you also avoid unsavory connotations that some might see in amica.
The typical way of expressing "since year [x]" is ab anno [x].1
If you wanted extra flair, you could even add (con)iunctae (-ae ending for feminine plural) in the beginning of the inscription, which all together yields a readable description:

Coniunctae in amicitia firmissima ab anno MCMXCVII
Joined in the sincerest/best/strongest friendship since 1997


Wonderful answer! Small point: are you sure you wanted "an extra flare" rather than "extra flair"?

Awesome thanks!

And if you want to say it, it's anno millesimo nongentesimo nonagesimo septimo

@BenKovitz In my defense, it was late at night, and I was sleepy. Fixed!

@SatyricaP If this ends up being the answer you choose, or if you feel your question is solved, don't forget to hit the check to mark it complete. Thanks and let me know if you have further questions about the translation!
